# Can somebody explain these C code?

Tags: c

**Code:**

```
enum {a, b};

int different(void)  
{  
    if (sizeof (enum {b, a}) != sizeof (int))  
        return a; // a == 1  
    return b; // b == 0 in C89, b == 1 in C99  
}
```

How `a==1` and `b==0` in `c89` and `b==1` in `c99` ?

I want to know how value of `a` in return `a` is 1 and return value of `b` changes in `c89` and `c99` ?

Comment: Well, can you add more details? As of now I cannot understand your question properly.

Comment: IIRC, so do other C's.

Comment: @AshishAhuja sizeof(enum {b, a}) is 4 and sizeof(int) is also 4 that means if(4!=4) then return a;, how the value of a is 1?

Comment: It's a scoping issue.  In C, `enum` values always start at `0` unless explicitly overridden.  However, in C89 you're getting the inner `enum` values, whereas in C99 you're getting the outer `enum` values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference between the C89 and C99 behavior is due to which `enum` definition is in scope.  In gcc, for C89 the inner definition is in effect for `return b`, while in C99 the outer definition is in effect for `return b`.

You can see this more clearly in the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum {a=5, b=6};

int different(void)
{
    if (sizeof(enum {b=7, a=8}) != sizeof(int))
        return a;
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", different());
}
```

In gcc, C89 mode gives 7 and C99 mode gives 6.